# How to change code, to create a recursive function

Tags: c, function, recursion, cs50

I am enrolled in a course called CS50. I have been learning about recursive functions recently, and although I have created a program called Collatz, that does what I want it to do, it does not have a recursive function inside as the function does not call itself. I am stuck and I can't figure out, how should I implement a recursive function, so that it looks neat and clean and calls itself.

I have tried to implement a function beside my main function. But I don't know how should that function look like, and how does it call itself.

```
//int x(int n);

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    //j is a counter for the number of times 'n' has to be calculated to get n==1
    int j = 0;

    //Ask for an integer
    printf("Int: ");
    scanf("%i", &n);

    //Check for 0 or less
    if (n <= 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR.")
        return 1;
    }

    //This is where recursion should be implemented
    while (n != 1)
    {
        if (n % 2 != 0)
        {
            while ((n % 2) != 0)
            {
                n = 3*n + 1 ;
                j++;
            }
        }
        else if ((n % 2) == 0)
        {
            while (n != 1)
            {
                n /= 2;
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("N: %i, number of times: %i \n", n,j);
}

/*
int x(int n)
{
    Should a recursive function be implemented here?
}
*/
```

Output is ok as is.
Output should be the number n which should be always 1, so to prove the program works and always get to number 1 , and amount of how many steps does it take to get to 1 from n.

Comment: Hint: Transforming a loop into a recursion can sometimes be quite tricky. It’s much simpler to take the original formulation of the Collatz problem and write it directly as a recursion. This is much more straightforward.

Comment: Other hint: to get familiar with recursion write the factorial function as recursive function.

Comment: Hint: are the inner `while` loops really needed in your code?

Answer (score 2):

Here you are.:)

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int collatz( unsigned int n )
{
    return n < 2 ? 0 : 1 + collatz( n % 2 == 0 ? n / 2 : 3 * n + 1 );
}

int main(void) 
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        unsigned int n;

        printf( "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): " );

        if ( scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;

        printf( "The number of steps is %u\n\n", collatz( n ) );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 19
The number of steps is 20

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
```

Answer (score 0):

For something like this I would recommend having a recursive function that return's the number of time's it took to get n to be equal to 1, since that's really all you want to keep track of. Since the code you are trying to make recursive is a loop, this make's it relatively easy to find what your base case (or exit condition) is going to be. In this case it's going to be when n == 1. So this lead's us to have something like this

```
int recursive_function(int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Now we need to focus on the logic, in order to keep track of the number of times the function has run (j essentially), we should make the function return the amount of times it's ran, then this will make it a lot easier to keep track of. So for this we'll add another return statement to the function, and make it run again since we already have our exit condition set up to tell us when to stop. After that you just need to add the logic in as well but we should end up with something like this:

```
int recursive_function(int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return 0;
    } else if (n % 2 != 0 ) {
        n = 3 * n + 1 ;
    } else if (n % 2 == 0) {
        n /= 2;
    }
    return 1 + recursive_function(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you don't know what a recursive function may look like or how it should call itself, here's a quick example.

```c
int fact(int n)
{
  if (n == 0) // this is the stopping case
    return 1;
  else
    return n * fact(n-1)); // this is what makes the function recursive
}
```

In this example, we are calculating the factorial of a number. We need to have a branch so when we know when we should stop calling the function. Fundamentally, this recursive function is the same as follows:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
{
  result = result * i;
}
```

Having a function being recursive means it's getting rid of a loop. I'd encourage you to start with your outermost while loop, and determine how you can eliminate that by implementing some return functions in various parts of your code to make it recursive. As a hint, it looks like you should have the following `if` statement:

```c
if (n != 1)
  return /* whatever is fit for your stopping case, should be an integer */
```

Another important thing to notice with recursive functions - the input needs to change when you make the function call itself. What I mean is, you should not have a function like this:

```
int x(int n)
{
  if (n == 0)
    return 1;
  else
    return x(n);
}
```

Inputting the same number and not having something like `return x(n-1)` will create an infinite loop, because there's no possible way to reach the stopping case, unless the original number inputted reaches the stopping case.

Of course, you may also add more calculations with your recursive call, and write something like `return 7 * x(n) / 2;`. Many beginners often forget this when learning about recursive functions and only want to write something like `return x(n-2);` for their return statements.

In your case, it looks like that the "stopping case" should be `if (n == 1)`.

Hopefully that should be enough to get you started!

Comment: You mean to return `n * fact(n - 1)` in your first example